# Simplify the equation in terms of function and coefficients?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

I have two fourth order differential equations and eight boundary conditions. I want to get my result in terms of function (Y) and coefficients (let say P1, P2 and so on). I used Dsolve to get the solution and simplified the result but still, the result is too long. How can I further transform it in to simplify form? Any help will be appreciated.

```
eq1 = X''''[Y] - 
A6*X''[Y] - (-Bi D5 + (A0^2 - Bi) D1 Cosh[
     A0 Y] + (4 A0^2 - Bi) D3 Cosh[2 A0 Y] + A0^2 D2 Sinh[A0 Y] - 
   Bi D2 Sinh[A0 Y] + 4 A0^2 D4 Sinh[2 A0 Y] - 
   Bi D4 Sinh[2 A0 Y])/k == 0;
eq2 = Z''''[Y] - 
A6*Z''[Y] + (Bi (D5 + D1 Cosh[A0 Y] + D3 Cosh[2 A0 Y] + 
     D2 Sinh[A0 Y] + D4 Sinh[2 A0 Y]))/k == 0;

Simplify[DSolveValue[{eq1, eq2, Z[0]== 0, X''[t]==B3, Z''[t]== 0, X[t] == Z[t],B2 == -k*X'[t] - Z'[t]}, {X[Y], Z[Y]}, Y]]
```

Note: A0,A6,B2,B3,B4,D1 to D5,Bi,k are constant values.

Comment: Do you have any reason to expect that further simplifications are in fact possible?

Comment: What if any constraints exist on the constants? Are any real, or nonnegative, or positive, or negative, or restricted to an interval? Adding corresponding assumptions to `Simplify` might help.

Comment: All the constants are real and positive and not restricted to an interval @BobHanlon

Comment: Actually, I want to simplify my answer and I think in Mathematica there should be a way to simplify the result in a manner. @AccidentalFourierTransform

Comment: Then you should use `Assuming[Thread[{A0, A6, B2, B3, Bi, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, k} > 0],
 Simplify[
  DSolveValue[
   {eq1, eq2, Z[0] == 0, X''[t] == B3, Z''[t] == 0,
    X[t] == Z[t], B2 == -k*X'[t] - Z'[t]},
   {X[Y], Z[Y]}, Y]]]`. Although in this case the result does not simplify further, you should not withhold information from Mathematica. You might also try using `FullSimplify` but it will take an inordinate amount of time and there is no guarantee that further simplification is possible.